# Django cannot resolve field when annotating

Tags: python, django

I have the following model:

```
from django.db import models

from tvproject_api.models import TVUser

class Watched(models.Model):
    tvuser = models.ForeignKey(TVUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='watched_tvuser')
    show_id = models.IntegerField()
    season_id = models.IntegerField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['tvuser', 'show_id', 'season_id']]
```

I'm trying to annotate the TVUser model with a count of this by doing,

```
TVUser.objects.filter().annotate(watched_count=Count('watched_tvuser'))
```

But this gives me,

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'watched_tvuser' into field.
```

Weirdly, I have another model that looks almost exactly like the `Watched` model:

```
from django.db import models

from tvproject_api.models import TVUser


class Watchlist(models.Model):
    tvuser = models.ForeignKey(TVUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='watchlist_tvuser')
    show_id = models.IntegerField()
    season_id = models.IntegerField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['tvuser', 'show_id', 'season_id']]
```

And this works totally fine:

```
TVUser.objects.filter().annotate(watched_count=Count('watchlist_tvuser'))
```

Not sure what the problem here is. I'm able to annotate lots of different fields, but the one for `watched_tvuser` is the only one not working.

Comment: what does the `TVUser` model look like?

Comment: This might sound silly to ask but did you run your migrations?

Comment: Have you added the app that contains the `Watched` model to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting?

Comment: Could you check from a shell
obj = TVUser.objects.first()
obj.watchlist_tvuser.all() 
works or not?
@Human Cyborg Relations

Comment: @paraschauhan Yeah that works. But if I do obj.watched_tvuser.all(), it fails with "TVUser object has no attribute watched_user"

Comment: @IainShelvington Yep

Comment: @JervenClark Yes, migrations have been successfully run

Comment: @MatthewBarlowe It basically has a username, description, and password field. There's a few others but I don't see them conflicting with the watched field

Comment: @HumanCyborgRelations where is the file that contains `Watched` located and can you share the INSTALLED_APPS section of your settings? Are you able to access `obj.tvuser` from a `Watched` instance?

Comment: This issue looks of migrations, can you re-migrate or something that can migrate your field again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I wasn't exporting the Watched model from my models/**init**.py file